# How to modify the behavior of method definitions themselves in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, metaprogramming

### The Setup

I recently started working with Ruby after writing mostly very functional/compositional JS and some point free clojure.

I've learned that Ruby is very "open" to modification or extension. Neato.

I set myself a challenge, and promptly failed to make any progress towards it. Likely this is because I'm still in the "Don't know what terms to search" stage of learning Ruby.

### My Goal

Write a module such that when used it does two things...

1. Causes all methods defined on the module/class to become static
2. Causes all methods defined on the module/class to return a lambda of themselves instead

### Concrete Examples

For rule 1 this would look something like

```
class TestClass
  include ThingIWannaMake
  def something
    puts "hello world"
  end
end
```

would effectively be

```
class TestClass
  def self.something
    puts "hello world"
  end
end
```

while for rule 2 this

```
class TestClass
  include ThingIWannaMake
  def something(a)
    puts a
  end
end
```

would mean the same as

```
class TestClass
  def self.something
    -> a { puts a }
  end
end
```

Leading to a final, ideal, output (for the second input) being...

```
class TestClass
  def self.something
    -> a { puts a }
  end
end
```

### The Question(s)

This task was primarily taken on as a learning exercise in Ruby so my primary interest is in the terms and tutorials that would teach my how I could, or why I could not, achieve this goal or another one like it.

### Edits/Responses

While this question was wonderfully answered (thank you!) the majority of feedback was negative. Please allow me to address some of the points here, for future readers who may stumble across this as well as in response to the comments themselves.

1. **Word Choice** - many of the words and terms I used were/are incorrect. Most grievous was the use of "static [method]". Thanks to the comments below I now know that a much more accurate understanding of the concept within the Ruby world would be a "class [method]". My mistake there is an extension of my place as a "Ruby foreigner" still learning both languages and concepts. I believe that this language mistake is indicative of, and likely very common to, new Ruby users. As such I will leave the mistake, in light of the corrections below, in the hope that my failures teach future learners who follow.
2. **The Goal Was Bad** - While I don't know if a comment response is any kind of place to change someone's core beliefs about what is or is not "good programming" I may be able to at least provide some empathy for my position by explaining some of the concepts I was using as points of reference. Closest is [monkey-patching](https://www.audero.it/blog/2016/12/05/monkey-patching-javascript/) in javascript. Most commonly used (for me) are [macros](https://clojure.org/reference/macros) in clojure. But perhaps most applicable are [reader](https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html) [macros](https://lisp-lang.org/wiki/article/reader-macros) from common lisp. With this task I was trying, to some extent, to "calibrate" my expectations for Ruby relative to these more familiar well liked tools.
3. added a code example of all parts working in unison.

Thank you again for the answers! Hopefully these clarifications make this at least a less frustrating question to read.

Comment: So really rule 2 should define `def self.something; -> (a) { puts a}; end` because of rule 1 is that correct? Also how should rule 2 get "a" when it is not passed as an argument? Should it be called as `TestClass.new.something.call("a")` or are you somehow expecting `TestClass.new.something("a") #=> Proc` even though `something` no longer accepts the arguments defined by its initial definition? [Rule 2](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/UtterOpulentRobots#main.rb) is much easier to solve but including the implications of rule 1 makes it more difficult and the cross over here is unclear

Comment: "static" doesn't really map well to Ruby, certainly not by shifting all the instance methods to class methods.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. 1) Your title and your body don't match. According to your title, you want to modify the behavior of *method definitions*, according to the question body, you want to modify the behavior of *methods*. Those are two very different things. Which one is it? 2) According to your requirement #1, you want all methods to become "static", but you don't explain what you mean by that. Ruby does not have static methods, all methods are always dynamic. 3) According to your last paragraph, you are mainly looking for resources, but resource requests are off-topic.

Comment: Rule 1 is doable but only under known circumstances because you cannot take an instance method definition and bind it to the class.

Comment: Asking how to do a more realistic metaprogramming example would get better answers. Maybe ask how to curry? Avoid jargon hoisted from other programming languages. Ruby does not have the terms lamba nor static.

Comment: Excuse me, Ruby does have [a thing called lambda](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh this is going to be terrible, but you asked for it!

Here's what we're making work:

```rb
class TestClass
  include Lambdifier
  def something
    puts "hello world"
  end
end
TestClass.something.call
# hello world
# => nil
```

1. The first conundrum to solve is the fact that at the point when `Lambdifier` is included **there are no methods defined yet**. Ruby's definitions run sequentially. So we're going to have to run a piece of code whenever a method is **added** to the class. Conveniently there's a Ruby hook `method_added` that does just that.
2. Another issue would be that you technically can unbind methods from their original owners and rebind them to new ones via `instance_method` and `bind`, but **Ruby still requires the new owner to be of the same class or its descendant**. We can work around this by creating an owner we need from the original class, effectively making it a singleton. And Ruby's standard library provides this solution already, so we'll make use of it and not reinvent the wheel. And since the methods we need are already bound to a valid receiver, rebinding won't be necessary.

   One could say that it's a major deviation as this doesn't not attach instance methods to their respective **class**, but doing so breaks the type system, because an object's class is not guaranteed to be type-compatible to its instances (although realistically, even instances of subclasses may not be), so the fact that it's not allowed is probably for the better.

   *(There is at least one exception to this rule, `Class`, which is an instance of itself... but there isn't much you can do with it, as it's treated by the language in a rather special way.)*

```
require "singleton"

module Lambdifier
  def self.included(base)
    base.include ::Singleton
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(name)
      prior_method = instance.method(name)
      define_singleton_method(name) { prior_method }
    end
  end
end

class TestClass
  include Lambdifier
  def something
    puts "hello world"
  end
end

TestClass.something.call
# hello world
# => nil
```

A few remarks:

- The closest thing to "static methods" in Ruby are "singleton methods". They're essentially methods, but are defined on a value's "singleton class", a lazily defined class (in that it doesn't exist until accessed) just for this value. And `define_singleton_method` is essentially `singleton_class.define_method`. And the same thing as doing `define_method` or `def` in a `class << self` block.
- The return values of methods aren't technically lambdas, but they "quack like lambdas", in that they're callables (have a `call` method). Most prominent callables in Ruby are procs and lambdas, but there are neither — these are `Method`s:

  ```rb
  TestClass.something
  # => #<Method: TestClass#something>
  ```
- The instance methods are still there in their original form! You can "undefine" them with `undef_method` if you need to though. It replaces a method with a "tombstone" inside the class which causes Ruby to stop going up the ancestor chain and raise `NoMethodError`.

  ```rb
  TestClass.instance_methods(false)
  # => [:something]
  TestClass.undef_method(:something) # Where to insert? Left as an exercise :)
  TestClass.send(:new).something # Singleton hides .new...
  # !> NoMethodError: undefined method `something' for #<TestClass:...>
  TestClass.something.call
  # hello world
  # => nil
  ```

  Mind you, if you inline `prior_method` this won't work, as class methods will be looking up their counterparts on `instance` on every call.

  Could you make **instance** methods return "lambdas of themselves" **before** making them "static"? Hm... to return a "lambda" you're not going to need arguments, so you'd have to change the arity to 0, which would make the interface incompatible (even more so, because return type change already happened). So probably not.

Comment: Previously the worst metaprogramming offender I built was using `method(:method)`. This one tops it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for in your title is not possible:

> How to modify the behavior of method definitions themselves in Ruby

You cannot change the behavior of method definitions. They are built into the language, and language features cannot be modified in Ruby, like in most other languages as well.

Your rule #1 is impossible as well: you are changing what `self` is, which means that any references to `self` will highly likely be broken, since the method is written under the assumption that `self` is an instance of `TestClass`, but it will be executed with `self` being an instance of `Class`. `TestClass` and `Class` have completely different "shapes", so this is pretty much guaranteed to break.

Rule #2 *might* be possible to implement using the [`Method#curry`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-curry) method:

```ruby
class TestClass
  def something(a)
    puts a
  end
end

unbound_method = TestClass.public_instance_method(:something)
TestClass.define_method(:something) { unbound_method.bind(self).curry }
```

This is really simple. In fact, a significant part of the complexity here is caused by your requirement that this transformation should be triggered by mixin inheritance, which simply has nothing to do with the problem at all.

```ruby
module MakeMethodsLambdas
  module LambdaMethodMaker
    def method_added(meth)
      unbound_method = public_instance_method(meth)
      prepend(Module.new do
        define_method(meth) { unbound_method.bind(self).curry }
      end)

      super
    end
  end

  def self.included(mod)
    class << mod
      prepend LambdaMethodMaker
    end
  end
end

class TestClass
  include MakeMethodsLambdas
  def something(a)
    puts a
  end
end

t = TestClass.new
l = t.something
l.('Hello')
# Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the metaprogramming and introspection methods are in [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html). [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) is useful for metaprogramming.

But what you're asking for is very strange, modules should add functionality, not quietly change existing functionality. A more realistic metaprogramming question would get a better answer. Maybe ask how to curry?

[D-side made it work as you've described it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348034/14660), so I'll cover how to do it the Ruby way.

"static" is not a concept in Ruby, but if you want to make all the instance methods into class methods wrap them in a `class << self` block.

```
class TestClass
  class << self
    def something
      puts "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

If you want a reference to an instance method, use [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method).

```
method = TestClass.method(:something)
method.call()
```

Comment: I think the intention is to change how `def xxxx` works when `ThingIWannaMake` is included in a class.

Comment: I expect "static method" == "class method".

Comment: @engineersmnky It's such an odd metaprogramming request that it's difficult to answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky: In that case, the answer is trivial: how `def xxx` works cannot be changed.

Comment: @Schwern Odd yes but [Rule 2](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/UtterOpulentRobots#main.rb) is very "doable" although illogical. Rule 1 is reasonably nonsensical.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I guess I meant "change the end result of defining an instance method".

Comment: Between me and @D-Side I think we got all the angles covered. Amazing.

Comment: @engineersmnky: The OP however *explicitly* writes "modify the behavior of method definitions themselves", which is impossible. On the other hand, in the question body, "Causes all methods defined on the module/class to become static" is used, which can be interpreted in at least three different ways: change all methods that are *already defined* (which however is contradicted by the code examples), change how method definitions work (which is impossible), change the methods after they are defined (which is possible, but icky).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Examples are meant to be clarifying.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree with all of your assertions. Additionally the examples are contradictory as rule 1 has a direct impact on rule 2 but this impact is not shown. By brute force deduction (ignoring all words and looking at only the code) `def something(a); puts a; end` seems like it should be removed completely and its functional mechanism should be akin to `def self.something; -> a {puts a}; end` which is completely impossible.

Comment: To a great extent this question can be seen as attempting to understand what even is possible. This answer really helps clarify that Ruby would prefer this kind of task be done with a tool defined by the language itself, rather than a tool defined by the developer. It also helps clarify where some of the limits are on what a developer can hope to define.